# How do i create a static file in django

Tags: python, django, static

Please how can I correct this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qoutd.jpg)

I keep getting errors connecting BASE_DIRS to my static files

Comment: Welcome to SO! [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Please include error while you post a question

Comment: what is the error you are getting? alot of things could be happening and we would not like to get irrelevant. please include the error message

Answer (score 0):

The Base Directory will be like that.

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```